# Browser is still able to access internet after changing wrong proxy

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, netsh

I use following command to change proxy on my machine:

```
netsh winhttp set proxy x.x.x.x:port

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  x.x.x.x:port
    Bypass List     :  (none)
```

This used the wrong proxy on purpose. I expected not be able to access to the internet via browser. The result is I was still able access internet.

I try another way (follow guide in this link http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819961). I created following script:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000000
"ProxyServer"="http://x.x.x.x:port"
"ProxyOverride"="<local>"
```

I save this script in to .reg file and execute it. Checked in the registry again. New value was filled. But I was still access to the internet via browser.

Comment: Curious: Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The WinHTTP proxy settings aren't used by WinINET, the network stack used by Internet Explorer.

Using the registry script changes WinINET's proxy settings, but you the format of the `ProxyServer` key's value should be like so: `http=127.0.0.1:8888;https=127.0.0.1:8888;ftp=127.0.0.1:8888`